# Frete personalizado para cada região do mesmo CEP

Tags: woocommerce, plugin-wordpress

Me deparei com um desafio que ainda não encontrei uma solução.

Estou utilizando o woocommerce. E meu cliente vai ele mesmo se encarregar das entregas, já que é apenas dentro da cidade, mas para isso ele precisa de valores personalizados conforme a região, ou o bairro no caso. Porém como a cidade é relativamente pequena, ainda possui um CEP único para sua totalidade.

Eu preciso restringir áreas e valores personalizados, e não sei qual o melhor caminho para isso, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz pelo bairro mesmo,

Mas é importante que as pessoas não digitem o bairro, pois cada pessoa pode digitar um bairro diferente do que voce espera. Coloca un select no campo bairro.